# I will drive into town... but I can't drive

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

My girlfriend messaged me earlier to say "I will drive into town with my mother". I thought this was odd, since she doesn't have a licence. Turns out she meant that her mother will be driving, and she pointed out that it is perfectly fine to say "I will drive" in that case, citing the second usage of the verb from [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive).

I guess she is right then. Really though? *I drive,* can also mean *I will be in a vehicle that somebody else is actually driving?*

Comment: She could've said "*We will drive to the town with my mother.*" and that would've made more sense. I've never heard someone else saying this before. The dictionary entry doesn't provide an example sentence for this kind of usage.

Comment: @Neeku I've found another dictionary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Link please?

Comment: @Neeku I was assuming you were using 'the dictionary' in the way it is most commonly used here, as if there were only the one (the contributor has got hold of). Were you referring to M-W (which hasn't been mentioned by name so far) here? Their definition certainly licenses the 'travel by car' sense. And though ambiguous, it's certainly acceptable, at least in the UK.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was referring to *the dictionary entry* the O.P. has provided the link in their post.

Comment: "We drove to town" "She drove to town" "I drove to town" "They drove to town". It's the same word all four times.  or "I will drive to town" "She will drive to town" "We will drive to town" "They will drive to town"  It's the same word all four times.  It's ambiguous (but so what).  Note that if there happened to be a vehicle that needs TWO driving positions (which would be totally unsurprising - for example there are certain fire equipment, construction gear that has this), they "the two brothers will drive to town" is similarly ambiguous (it's unclear if they're in operation or just psngrs)

Comment: {I don't know what *"We went for a drive"* is, maybe it was mentioned incidentally.}  Final proof: **"I will drive into town with my mother"** (note - copied/pasted from the OP) "We will drive into town with my mother" "They will drive into town with my mother" "The Smith family will drive into town with my mother" Note that **it's just a technical coincidence** that at the moment cars happen to require 1x driver. In a few years they will require 0x drivers. Many trucks, etc, require 2x drivers.  {And consider, as I said, the identical "sail" situation.}

Comment: Please add attributions when linking (eg 'M-W', not 'here'): When you find a useful resource that can help answer a question ... make sure you do all of the following:

Provide a link to the original page or answer
Quote only the relevant portion
Provide the name of the original author [/reference work]
...  always give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link to it. [StackExchange Meta]

Comment: That's better @Joe Blow. That seems like a good explanation to me. I would accept that answer if it were possible, I will +1 your comment.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16856/discussion-on-question-by-hellishheat-i-will-drive-into-town-but-i-cant-driv).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit pedantic to quibble over such use of ***drive***. I've never heard anyone take issue with...

> *He is sailing to Calais this afternoon
>
>    He flew to New York yesterday*

...in contexts where ***he*** is a passenger (not a sailor or a pilot).

Comment: I couldn't agree more.  I * cough * said this in a comment above.  Note too the "converse" explanatory viewpoint: It is now utterly normal for cars to have 0x drivers, and it's commonplace that certain vehicles actually have two drivers.

Comment: @Joe: I [cough, cough] upvoted your comment straight away - and now I've just seen the one about ***sail***, I've upvoted that too. I seem to remember seeing that driverless cars are due to be legalised on public roads in the UK next year, but so far as I know there aren't yet any pilotless passenger-carrying commercial flights. Despite the fact that autopilots are responsible for less air crashes than "pilot error".

Comment: It's a good job not many people verb _tandem_.

Comment: @Edwin: I don't have a problem with [*"We tandemmed around the New Forest today"*](http://www.enjoygram.com/sarah_chats), any more than *"I hoovered the bedroom carpet"*.

Comment: But "I will tandem into town with my mother" isn't used enough to decide if there will be one pedaller or two.

Comment: @Edwin: Or [***three?***](http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4/arts/images/1703goodies_competition.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4/arts/frontrow/the_goodies_competition.shtml&h=206&w=244&tbnid=zlkYEuYXOS4IcM:&zoom=1&tbnh=169&tbnw=200&usg=__xnibFIDFkotStSNV1EOE0eDv72U=&docid=TbjxykFc5EMYbM&itg=1&sa=X&ei=JMEEVLOsEdSY1AWflYGgBQ&ved=0CJcBEPwdMAo) I've never been sure whether The Goodies "three-pedaller" velocipede counts as a "tandem" or not. And if not, what do we call it? (Since the obvious contender ***trike*** has already been co-opted for three *wheels*)

Comment: Wikipedia has 'Tandems can have more than 2 riders — tandem refers to the arrangement of the riders one behind the other rather than the number of riders. Bicycles for three, four, or five riders are referred to as "triples" or "triplets", "quads" or "quadruplets", and "quints" or "quintuplets" respectively.' But isn't this off-road?

Answer (score -1):

The second usage of the verb is not taken properly in context. The use of "I" straight before "drive" means in context the first usage of the verb, to actually be driving the vehicle. If she had said something like "Mother drove us to town" or "we drove into town" or similar is far better, and in context puts the mother as the person doing the "driving" and the use of "us" means they both went (or are going, or will be going all depending on the tense used)

Comment: It's metonymy. Have you never said / heard 'The kettle is boiling'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So that is similar to 'The car is driving'? If an object can do something, that is not related to the OP's question for a person acting upon an object.

Comment: There's a difference with say 'This car drives well': that's the 'middle' usage (some would quibble about terminology here). I open the door / this door opens easily. With 'the kettle boiled', 'She wanted to get into Hollywood', and OP's meaning of 'I will drive into town with my mother', the literal truth isn't intended, but most people usually understand what actually _is_ intended. What OP's girlfriend said wasn't **incorrect**, but could have been better worded to avoid the confusion she occasioned OP because of the ambiguity.