# Do Americans use "driving" for a bus journey?

Tags: verbs

I haven't been in America all that long and I'm still getting used to English usage here. Sometimes I've heard people say they "drove" from Austin to Dallas, for example, in a context that strongly suggests they took a Megabus - is that a common usage, or am I reading this wrongly?

This question ([I will drive into town... but I can't drive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194337/i-will-drive-into-town-but-i-cant-drive)) seems related but not the same thing.

Comment: Acceptability is highly context-dependent (at least in the UK). A Tripadvisor report contains 'Photo taken from the bus as we drove past', and of course, this sort of sentence is idiomatic on both sides of the Atlantic. 'We went by bus – we drove from Bristol to Bath' is _not_ idiomatic in the UK, and 'We drove from Bristol to Bath by bus' is unacceptable in the UK.

Comment: Normally someone in the US would say they *rode* the bus.  However, the bus itself *drove* from Austin to Dallas, so they might say "we drove to Dallas".  One would not normally say "**I** drove to Dallas" if the mode of transportation was a bus.

Comment: You can also "hop a bus", particularly if the decision was a bit opportunistic or spontaneous.

Comment: NE American - I'd "drive" by bus only if employed (as driver) by Greyhound Bus Line. Otherwse, "ride" or "travel."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close out this question: everybody who commented on the question seems to agree that "driving" isn't commonly used in this situation, which is what I suspected in the first place.